# Infinispan - create custom cache store

Tags: cassandra, infinispan

Since Infinispan no longer maintains the official cassandra cache store, I'm trying to make one of my own (for Infinispan 7.1.1).

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to implement since I haven't found anything in the documentation about creating a custom cache store.

These are the classes I have (inspired by the latest version of infinispan-cachestore-mongodb - which is also deprecated since Infinispan 6.0.0 :D):

```
public class CassandraCache<K, V> {

    private Cluster cluster;
    private Session session;
    ...
}
```

---

```
public class CassandraEntry<K, V>
```

---

```
public class CassandraStore<K, V> implements AdvancedLoadWriteStore<K, V> {
    private InitializationContext context;
    private CassandraCache<K, V> cache;
    private CassandraStoreConfiguration configuration;

    @Override
    public void init(InitializationContext ctx) {
        context = ctx;
        configuration = ctx.getConfiguration();
        try {
            cache = new CassandraCache<K, V>(configuration);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new PersistenceException(e);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

---

```
public class CassandraStoreConfiguration extends AbstractStoreConfiguration {

  private String hosts;
  private String keyspace;
...
}
```

---

```
public class CassandraStoreConfigurationBuilder extends AbstractStoreConfigurationBuilder<CassandraStoreConfiguration, CassandraStoreConfigurationBuilder> {

  private String hosts;
  private String keyspace;
...
}
```

I'm trying to set it up like so (in scala):

```
object Infinispan {

  val m: EmbeddedCacheManager = new DefaultCacheManager(globalConfig, cacheConfig)  

  def globalConfig = {
    new GlobalConfigurationBuilder()
      .transport()
    .defaultTransport()
      .build()
  }

  def cacheConfig = {
    new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .persistence().addStore(classOf[CassandraStoreConfigurationBuilder])
      .fetchPersistentState(true)
      .preload(true)
      .shared(true)
      .hosts("localhost:9160")
      .keyspace("mykeyspace")
    .transaction()
      .transactionMode(TransactionMode.TRANSACTIONAL)
      .transactionManagerLookup(new GenericTransactionManagerLookup)
      .autoCommit(false).transactionProtocol(TransactionProtocol.DEFAULT)
      .lockingMode(LockingMode.PESSIMISTIC)
    .build()
  }

}
```

But I get an exception:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: org.infinispan.persistence.cassandra.configuration.CassandraStoreConfiguration cannot be cast to org.infinispan.configuration.cache.CustomStoreConfiguration
```

So I changed CassandraStoreConfiguration to extend CustomStoreConfiguration and CassandraStoreConfigurationBuilder to extend CustomStoreConfigurationBuilder

Now I get this exception:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: org.infinispan.configuration.cache.CustomStoreConfiguration cannot be cast to org.infinispan.persistence.cassandra.configuration.CassandraStoreConfiguration
```

Why would it try to cast CustomStoreConfiguration to CassandraStoreConfiguration?

Is there a decent guide to creating a custom cache store somewhere?

Comment: In my humble opinion, you'd be better off taking the [existing Cassandra store](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-cachestore-cassandra) and bringing it up to date. There are [plenty of cache store implementations in the main Infinispan repository](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/tree/master/persistence) to guide you and those are guaranteed to be up to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was simply missing a couple of annotations:

```
@BuiltBy(CassandraStoreConfigurationBuilder.class)
@ConfigurationFor(CassandraStore.class)
public class CassandraStoreConfiguration extends AbstractStoreConfiguration
```

---

```
@ConfiguredBy(CassandraStoreConfiguration.class)
public class CassandraStore<K, V> implements AdvancedLoadWriteStore<K, V>
```

Once these were added, everything started to work just fine.

Comment: Thank you for info! I've already sent a pull request with a fix for that.

Answer (score 4):

I strongly believe that our brand new Infinispan custom cache store archetype can really help you with your effort.

Please check it out: https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-cachestore-archetype

The README file contains necessary information how to use it.

Comment: I implemented the external-store one and I'm getting the exact same error message. This leads me to think that perhaps I'm configuring it wrong. Can you give me an example how one would configure a custom cache store created with your archetype? I'm doing it like this: new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .persistence().addStore(classOf[CustomStoreConfigurationBuilder])